# From which scripture is the concept of Shuddha Sattva from?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, moksha, gunas

According to Sri Vaishnavism, liberated souls who reach Vaikunta, the eternal inhabitants of Vaikunta, and Para Vasudeva, all have bodies made of Shuddha Sattva matter, which is achit that doesn't have rajas and tamas. This is unlike Prakriti, which is achit that has all 3 gunas.

So which scripture is this concept of Shuddha Sattva from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term is explained in Srimad Bhagavatam.

Shuddha sattva is a technical term to explain the fact that paramatman has only good qualities without any defects.

Here is a beautiful verse from [Bhagavatam](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/27/4) explaining this

> viśuddha-sattvaṁ tava dhāma śāntaṁ
>   tapo-mayaṁ dhvasta-rajas-tamaskam
>   māyā-mayo ’yaṁ guṇa-sampravāho
>   na vidyate te grahaṇānubandham

Translation:

> King Indra said: Your transcendental form, a manifestation of pure goodness, is undisturbed by change, shining with knowledge and devoid of passion and ignorance. In You does not exist the mighty flow of the modes of material nature, which is based on illusion and ignorance.